# 524 timeout error on aws ec2- hosted Magento1.9

Tags: amazon-ec2, timeout, magento-1.9, cloudflare

I am using magento application hosted on Aws ec2 large server. and Cloudflare for security due to increasing attacks.

Everything was working fine and no changes were made but suddenly I continuously started getting 524 timeout error and i have tried to debug and follow below steps but still website works at slow speed for few minutes and then goes down with same error. CPU usage shows only 25-30% and disc space shows more than 30%

Steps followed.

- deleted logs
- deleted cache
- also logged into mysql to kill Query which was taking more than 100 seconds.
- sudo service mysqld restart (to restart mysql- which was a success)
- sudo service httpd restart (to restart apache which was a success)
- restarted Ec2 server

Anything else you will recommend I should try?

Comment: Please post results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeo%'; B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%timeo%'; and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%abort%'; Post the query that took more than 100 seconds.

Comment: How many items are in your Magento online catalog?

Comment: Please also post results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%; and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%';  Thanks

Comment: should install New Relic and check whats going on.